# Pass a parameter to a field in another page ASPMVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a person class that has an index file that lists each person.

An Html.ActionLink points to another controller for notes on the person.

One person, many notes, so I want to pass the PersonID as a param and insert it into the new note form. The parameter is not the NoteID, ie the key

```
@Html.ActionLink("Note", "Create", "Note", new { id = item.PersonID }, null)
```

The PersonID is in the url that passes to the note form.

How do I get the PersonID into the Note form?

Many thanks,
Harry

Comment: This `ActionLink` passes the `id` value to the controller `Create` controller action on the `Note` controller.  It's then up to that action to actually use the value (including sending it to the view).  What does that action look like and how does it use the value?

Answer (score 0):

In your Create action method in the Note controller, you will receive the ID as a paramter to the action method if you include a parameter for it in the function:

```
public ActionResult Create(string id)
{

}
```

From there it is up to you to pass the id into the view you are using to construct the Create Note page.  If you have a Note model object and one of the properties is the PersonID, you might want to new up a new Note object, set the PersonID to the value passed in the parameter, and then pass the new Note object to the view page as the model:

```
return View(newNote);
```

Hope that is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can *knockout* it using the same name as u declared *ID*
Or.. just handle it on another Controller using 
the same name. *ID*:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ViewResult Create(int id)
    {
        return View(id); <--
    }
```

Then with razor-engine it comes with *@Model*